# i want to print out a certain part of a list

Tags: python, search

So i have a list that contains an object, but I wanted to do a searching algorithm with it, meaning that if the word is similar, it will show the items with the similar category. But there was an error.

code:

```
print("\nHere are the results of your search")
    if param == 'Electric Guitar':
        results = inventory[item_006:item_010]
```

Objects:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, hproduct, htype, hprice, havail):
        self.name = hproduct
        self.type = htype
        self.price = hprice
        self.avail = havail
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.type == other

item_001 = Product('Tyma TD-10E Dreadnought', 'Acoustic Guitar', 23450, 'In Stock')
item_002 = Product('Baton Rouge AR21C/ME Traveler', 'Acoustic Guitar', 14900, 'In Stock')
item_003 = Product('Phoebus Baby 30 GS Mini', 'Acoustic Guitar', 6900, 'In Stock')
item_004 = Product('Maestro Project X X1-V1 OM', 'Acoustic Guitar', 32500, 'In Stock')
item_005 = Product('Sire A4 Grand Auditorium', 'Acoustic Guitar', 27490, 'In Stock')

item_006 = Product('Tagima TW55', 'Electric Guitar', 9500, 'In Stock')
item_007 = Product('Epiphone G400 ', 'Electric Guitar', 19500, 'In Stock')
item_008 = Product('D’Angelico Premiere DC', 'Electric Guitar', 49000, 'In Stock')
item_009 = Product('PRS Silver Sky', 'Electric Guitar', 138950, 'In Stock')
item_010 = Product('Vintage V100 Reissued', 'Electric Guitar', 27950, 'In Stock')

item_011 = Product('Phoebus Buddie 30 GS-E', 'Bass Guitar', 8720, 'In Stock')
item_012 = Product('Sire U5', 'Bass Guitar', 27490, 'In Stock')
item_013 = Product('Lakland Skyline Vintage J', 'Bass Guitar', 82950, 'In Stock')
item_014 = Product('Schecter Model T Session 5', 'Bass Guitar', 45900, 'In Stock')
item_015 = Product('Tagima Millenium Coda 4', 'Bass Guitar', 14900, 'In Stock')

item_016 = Product('Boss Katana 50 Mk II ', 'Accessory', 15950, 'In Stock')
item_017 = Product('TC Electronic BH250 Micro Bass', 'Accessory', 18990, 'In Stock')
item_018 = Product('Kemper Profiler Powerhead', 'Accessory', 130000, 'In Stock')
item_019 = Product('Headrush Pedal Board', 'Accessory', 27490, 'In Stock')
item_020 = Product('NUX MG30', 'Accessory', 12900, 'In Stock')

inventory = [item_001, item_002, item_003, item_004, item_005, item_006, item_007, item_008, item_009, item_010, item_011, item_012, item_013, item_014, item_015, item_016, item_017, item_018, item_019, item_020]
```

desired output:

```
Tagima TW55                         Electric Guitar              9500     In Stock
Epiphone G400                       Electric Guitar              19500    In Stock
D’Angelico Premiere DC              Electric Guitar              49000    In Stock
PRS Silver Sky                      Electric Guitar              138950   In Stock
Vintage V100 Reissued               Electric Guitar              27950    In Stock
```

error:

```
slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Thank you for any tips and help.

Comment: What is `alist`?

Comment: the list that stores the objects

Comment: ```inventory[5:10]```?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to match all the object with the type equal to the parameter, you can do something more dynamic than hardcoding the positions of the results:

```
results = [obj for obj in inventory if obj.type == param]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

This mean you should implement `__index__` magic method in your object. [`__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__) needs to return integer, in your case with position in `list`. Consider following simple example

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Thing("' + self.name + '")'
    def __index__(self):
        return inventory.index(self)
uno = Thing("uno")
dos = Thing("dos")
tres = Thing("tres")
inventory = [uno,dos,tres]
print(inventory[:dos])
print(inventory[dos:])
print(inventory[dos:tres])
```

output

```
[Thing("uno")]
[Thing("dos"), Thing("tres")]
[Thing("dos")]
```

Disclaimer: this solution assume all your object are hold in exactly one list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is you are slicing a list using objects `item_006` and `item_010` in `inventory[item_006:item_010]`, while slice works with indexes as mentioned below

> [start : stop : steps]
>
> which means that slicing will start from index start  will go up to
> stop in step of steps.   Default value of start is 0, stop is last
> index of list  and for step it is 1

To get the desired ouput just do this:

```
param = "Electric Guitar"
results = [item for item in inventory if item.type == param]
print (results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct fix to what you've done is this.

```py
results = inventory[5:10]
```

You have to give slices integers as indices, not `Product`s.

However, in your case, it might be better simply to find the products with a `type` of `"Electric Guitar"`:

```py
results = [p for p in inventory if p.type == "Electric Guitar"]
```

If your full code ends up looking like

```py
if param == "Electric Guitar":
    results = [p for p in inventory if p.type == "Electric Guitar"]
elif param == "Acoustic Guitar":
    results = [p for p in inventory if p.type == "Acoustic Guitar"]
...
```

then you can simplify it to just:

```py
if param in {"Electric Guitar", "Acoustic Guitar", ...}:
    results = [p for p in inventory if p.type == param]
```

Comment: when i tried the other types like acoustic guitar, it says ```'str' object has no attribute 'price'```

Comment: @PythonnLearner What did you do exactly?

Comment: i implemented this to my code ```def binary(word, sett):
    first = 0
    last = len(sett) - 1
    asd = False
    while first<=last and not asd: 
        mid = (first + last)//2 
        if sett[mid].__eq__(word):
            asd = True
            return True
        else:
            if word < sett[mid]:
                last = mid - 1
            else:
                first = mid + 1
```

Comment: @PythonnLearner That’s just a binary search algorithm, that shouldn’t cause that `AttributeError`. The error should be coming from somewhere where you do `something.price`.